# How to preview of the multiple images that being upload before post to server using kendo upload control

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

It works fine for a single image whenever multiple images are uploaded then all the image previews are overwritten by the last image preview Here is My Code and  I am using Kendo Upload control.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                .Name("files").
                TemplateId("fileTemplate")
                .Async(a => a
                    .Save("Save", "Upload")
                    .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
                    .AutoUpload(false)).Events(events => events.Select("onSelect")))


    <script id="fileTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <span class='k-progress'></span>
        <div class='file-wrapper'>
            <img class='file-icon' /> <!-- here im trying to bind the image -->
            <h4 class='file-heading file-name-heading'>Name: #=name#</h4>
            <h4 class='file-heading file-size-heading'>Size: #=size# bytes</h4>
                <button type='button' class='k-upload-action'></button>
            </div>
        </script>

<script>
    function onSelect(e) {
        $.each(e.files, function (index, value) {
                    readMultipleFiles(value);
        });
    }

    function readMultipleFiles(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            // bind the file content
            $("img").attr({ src: e.target.result });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .file-icon {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 48px;
        height: 48px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 13.5px;
    }

    #example .file-heading {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 450px;
        margin: 0 0 0 20px;
        height: 25px;
        -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
        -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #example .file-name-heading {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #example .file-size-heading {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    li.k-file .file-wrapper .k-upload-action {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    li.k-file div.file-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 75px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please help me I am struggling with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mistake you have applied the data to all the images. You have to apply image data to its specific template's img tag.

Please update below JS function in your code and check it. Let me know if its not working.

```
function readMultipleFiles(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var fileobj = file;
        $('.k-file[data-uid="' + fileobj.uid + '"]').find('img').attr({ src: e.target.result });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it Works